# Jboss SSO (non-clustered) logout only works on same webapp as login

Tags: jboss

I have two WARs in an EAR. Each WAR has its own login.jsp and logout.jsp.

Logging in via webapp1 works fine, and then when I browse to webapp2, I'm also logged in there. If I go to webapp1/logout.jsp, I get logged out of both applications (browsing to webapp1 or webapp2 both give me a login page).

However, if I log in via webapp1, but try to log out using webapp2/logout.jsp, it has no effect. If I navigate to webapp1/index.jsp or webapp2/index.jsp, I'm still logged in (and the other way around has the same issue, i.e. log in via webapp2 but logout via webapp1).

The logout.jsp calls:

```
session.invalidate();
request.logout();
```

I'm using Jboss EAP 6.1.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out we'd added the `<sso />` element to the `<virtual-server...` element in standalone.xml, but we'd also added the `SingleSignOn` valve to the jboss-web.xml of each WAR. It appears that the latter was adding a second singlesignon valve in to the chain.

So, removing the valves from the jboss-web.xml files fixed the issue - the `<sso />` tag is sufficient to enable sso (despite what a lot of blog posts on the internet claim).

(I don't feel too bad finding out it was my mistake given that no one else answered my question.)